# Execute an action only when a directory is non empty in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to execute the action in the playbook, only when a directory is non-empty.

How to check the condition in `when:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, Here you should change action from `debug` to something which you want.

Here we are gathering list of files on that directory(`no which you want to perform action`)

and using `debug` we are printing the output of that particular command.

> **Note:** You should change my example of `debug` with your action you want.

```
---
- hosts: "localhost"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "Looking for files"
    command: ls /path/to/directory
    register: command_output
  - name: "Looking for output"
    debug:
     msg: "{{command_output}}"
    when: command_output.stdout != ""
```